# SQL OPENQUERY UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I am trying to update Oracle table from SQL server. I have setup a linked server, and i am able to update this table using following query.

```
UPDATE OPENQUERY(LNK_SRV, 'SELECT BOGNUMBER, BOGDATA FROM DATA.BOGTAB')
SET BOGNUMBER = 009
WHERE BOGDATA = 'LIVE'
```

Now the above query will be very slow as you can imagine, as entire data from table DATA.BOGTAB is not filtered and the where clause is SQL server query.

I want to optimize the above query, so that it is fast and the one way i see to do it is executing this update statement on remote server by creating a dynamic query and executing it.
I think it will help if the where clause is somehow embeded in the query which will be executed on remote server, as it will give a filtered dataset. 
Can anybody please help me figure out how i can dynamically create a query and execute this update statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried a few thing and i have got a solution for this...

```
DECLARE @VC_DYN_QUERY NVARCHAR(255)
SET @VC_DYN_QUERY = 'UPDATE DATA.BOGTAB SET BOGNUMBER = 009 WHERE BOGDATA = ''LIVE'''
EXECUTE (@VC_DYN_QUERY) AT LNK_SRV
```

This will just execute the dynamic query that we prepare on remote server, this is will be a lot faster, as there is no heavy data that we transfer over the network, or we do not have any expensive comparison in where clause on SQL server.

Hope somebody benefits from this, like i did. Thanks!